# DbNotProvisioned Exception

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync remote SQL database with local SQL database using microsoft sync framework

When It runs for local SQL for 2 different database it works like charm , when I try same code for remote database - local database sync , it ends up with error

> The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables.

How to overcome with above exception

Here is my code

> ```
>             var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);
>             if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(tableName))
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     var scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(tableName);
>                     scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, serverConn));
>                     serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
>                     serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
>                     serverProvision.Apply();
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception exception)
>                 {
>                     MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
>                 }
>             }
> ```

```
            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn);
            if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(tableName))
            {
                try
                {
                    var scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(tableName, serverConn);
                    clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
                    clientProvision.Apply();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                }
            }

            var serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(tableName, serverConn);
            var clientProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(tableName, clientConn);
            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator{Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload,LocalProvider = clientProvider, RemoteProvider = serverProvider};

            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += ProgramApplyChangeFailed;               
            syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

Thanks

Vinay

Comment: are you calling the provisioning code before calling Synchronize()? have you check the server if the provisioning actually succeeds? check if the following tables exists: scope_info, scope_config, etc...and check under what schema are they created (dbo?)

Comment: My remote database is not under dbo .. its under specific user / schema  , same user / schema is created on my local database , sync tables are exist

Comment: try setting the ObjectSchema property explicitly

Comment: Didn't work for me (ObjectSchema) , My remote server is SQL server 2005 and my client server is 2008 , is that makes any issue in synchronization ?

Comment: is your SQL 2005 at least on SP2? have you set the ObjectSchema before you called Synchronize()?

Comment: its 9.00.3080 means its SP2 ,  and While applying ObjectSchema I am getting given exception

Comment: what's the schema used for both databases? can you post snippet of your sync code?

Comment: its username as schema- code is in already posted in question

Comment: something I found is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845032%28v=sql.100%29.aspx  - permission page .. can you let me know how to provide required  permissions to database user

Comment: am referring to the synchronization code, the above code is for provisioning... can you post a code how you set up the providers prior to calling Synchronize(). as to granting permissions you can do that in SSMS, right click the user and grant the permissions. if you want TSQL, just google how to use GRANT statements

Comment: FYI : I am getting error in provisioning !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was permission problem over shared database hosting !

Thanks JuneT for all your help.

Thank you all.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I had another case in which this happened: the default schema for the user, was not the schema the tables I wanted to sync where in...
And that doesn't work :-)
changed the default schema for the sync db user to the same schema the tables were in and then it worked seamlessly!